# imprimir en impresora lo de la JTable de factura

Tags: java, eclipse, programación-funcional, eclipse-oxygen

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import javax.swing.JTabbedPane;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;

import Variables.Factura;

import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.border.TitledBorder;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.SystemColor;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.DefaultComboBoxModel;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.print.PrinterException;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.text.MessageFormat;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;

public class YAI extends JFrame {

private JPanel contentPane;
private JTextField textField;
private JTextField tnumero;
private JTextField tfecha;
private JTextField tcodigo;
private JTextField tnombre;
private JTextField tmarca;
private JTextField tcantidad;
private JTextField tprecio;
private JTable tablefactura;
private JTable tableVehiculo;
private JTextField tano;
private JTable table;

/**
 * Launch the application.
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                YAI frame = new YAI();
                frame.setVisible(true);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}

/**
 * Create the frame.
 */
public YAI() {
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setBounds(100, 100, 757, 522);
    contentPane = new JPanel();
    contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
    setContentPane(contentPane);
    contentPane.setLayout(null);
    
    JTabbedPane tabbedPane = new JTabbedPane(JTabbedPane.TOP);
    tabbedPane.setBounds(0, 0, 741, 483);
    contentPane.add(tabbedPane);
    
    JPanel Productos = new JPanel();
    Productos.setToolTipText("");
    tabbedPane.addTab("Productos", null, Productos, null);
    Productos.setLayout(null);
    
    JLabel tablev = new JLabel("Productos");
    tablev.setBounds(10, 11, 70, 22);
    Productos.add(tablev);
    
    textField = new JTextField();
    textField.setBounds(79, 12, 427, 20);
    Productos.add(textField);
    textField.setColumns(10);
    
    JButton btnBuscar = new JButton("Buscar");
    btnBuscar.setBounds(637, 11, 89, 23);
    Productos.add(btnBuscar);
    
    
    
    JButton btnAgregar = new JButton("Agregar");
    btnAgregar.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            
            AggVehiculo agregarv = new AggVehiculo();
            agregarv.setVisible(true);
            
        }
    });
    btnAgregar.setBounds(637, 44, 89, 23);
    Productos.add(btnAgregar);
    
    JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane();
    scrollPane.setBounds(10, 48, 610, 359);
    Productos.add(scrollPane);
    
    table = new JTable();
    scrollPane.setViewportView(table);
    table.setModel(new DefaultTableModel(
        new Object[][] {
        },
        new String[] {
            "C\u00F3digo", "Nombre", "Marca", "Color", "Combustible", "A\u00F1o", "Precio"
        }
    ));
    table.setEditingRow(0);
    table.setEditingColumn(0);
    

    JPanel Clientes = new JPanel();
    tabbedPane.addTab("Clientes", null, Clientes, null);
    Clientes.setLayout(null);
    
    JButton btnAgregarCliente = new JButton("Agregar Cliente");
    btnAgregarCliente.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            AgreCliente ac = new AgreCliente();
            ac.setVisible(true);
        }
    });
    btnAgregarCliente.setBounds(10, 369, 143, 23);
    Clientes.add(btnAgregarCliente);
    
    JPanel Vendedores = new JPanel();
    Vendedores.setBorder(new TitledBorder(null, "Facturaci\u00F3n", TitledBorder.RIGHT, TitledBorder.TOP, null, null));
    tabbedPane.addTab("Factura", null, Vendedores, null);
    Vendedores.setLayout(null);
    
    JLabel lblNoFactura = new JLabel("No. Factura");
    lblNoFactura.setBounds(10, 11, 65, 20);
    Vendedores.add(lblNoFactura);
    
    tnumero = new JTextField();
    tnumero.setBounds(75, 11, 86, 20);
    Vendedores.add(tnumero);
    tnumero.setColumns(10);
    
    JLabel lblFecha = new JLabel("Fecha");
    lblFecha.setBounds(71, 54, 46, 14);
    Vendedores.add(lblFecha);
    
    tfecha = new JTextField();
    tfecha.setBounds(105, 51, 86, 20);
    Vendedores.add(tfecha);
    tfecha.setColumns(10);
    
    JLabel lblCodigo = new JLabel("Codigo");
    lblCodigo.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 15));
    lblCodigo.setBounds(10, 108, 65, 20);
    Vendedores.add(lblCodigo);
    
    JLabel lblModelo = new JLabel("Nombre");
    lblModelo.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 15));
    lblModelo.setBounds(71, 108, 76, 20);
    Vendedores.add(lblModelo);
    
    JLabel lblMarca = new JLabel("Marca");
    lblMarca.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 15));
    lblMarca.setBounds(228, 108, 46, 20);
    Vendedores.add(lblMarca);
    
    JLabel lblCantidad_1 = new JLabel("Cantidad");
    lblCantidad_1.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 15));
    lblCantidad_1.setBounds(373, 108, 65, 20);
    Vendedores.add(lblCantidad_1);
    
    JLabel lblPrecio = new JLabel("Precio");
    lblPrecio.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 15));
    lblPrecio.setBounds(481, 108, 54, 20);
    Vendedores.add(lblPrecio);
    
    JLabel lblTotal = new JLabel("Total");
    lblTotal.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 15));
    lblTotal.setBounds(585, 108, 46, 20);
    Vendedores.add(lblTotal);
    
    tcodigo = new JTextField();
    tcodigo.setBounds(10, 134, 54, 20);
    Vendedores.add(tcodigo);
    tcodigo.setColumns(10);
    
    tnombre = new JTextField();
    tnombre.setBounds(71, 134, 120, 20);
    Vendedores.add(tnombre);
    tnombre.setColumns(10);
    
    tano = new JTextField();
    tano.setBounds(290, 134, 73, 20);
    Vendedores.add(tano);
    tano.setColumns(10);
    
    tmarca = new JTextField();
    tmarca.setBounds(201, 134, 86, 20);
    Vendedores.add(tmarca);
    tmarca.setColumns(10);
    
    tcantidad = new JTextField();
    tcantidad.setBounds(373, 134, 105, 20);
    Vendedores.add(tcantidad);
    tcantidad.setColumns(10);
    
    tprecio = new JTextField();
    tprecio.setBounds(481, 134, 97, 20);
    Vendedores.add(tprecio);
    tprecio.setColumns(10);
    
    JPanel panel_2 = new JPanel();
    panel_2.setBounds(10, 165, 645, 236);
    Vendedores.add(panel_2);
    panel_2.setLayout(null);
    
    JScrollPane scrollPane_2 = new JScrollPane();
    scrollPane_2.setBounds(0, 0, 645, 236);
    panel_2.add(scrollPane_2);
    
    tablefactura = new JTable();
    scrollPane_2.setViewportView(tablefactura);
    tablefactura.setModel(new DefaultTableModel(
        new Object[][] {
        },
        new String[] {
            "C\u00F3digo", "Nombre", "Marca", "Año", "Cantidad", "Precio", "Total"
        }
    ));
    
    JLabel lblYarlinAutosImport = new JLabel("Yarlin Autos Import S.A");
    lblYarlinAutosImport.setForeground(new Color(0, 0, 205));
    lblYarlinAutosImport.setFont(new Font("Britannic Bold", Font.PLAIN, 20));
    lblYarlinAutosImport.setBounds(242, 11, 227, 30);
    Vendedores.add(lblYarlinAutosImport);
    
    JLabel lblNewLabel_1 = new JLabel("Carretera Mella/K #5 \r\n");
    lblNewLabel_1.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 13));
    lblNewLabel_1.setBounds(284, 33, 131, 25);
    Vendedores.add(lblNewLabel_1);
    
    JLabel lblTell = new JLabel("Tell: 829-981-9169 ");
    lblTell.setBounds(294, 54, 105, 14);
    Vendedores.add(lblTell);
    
    JButton btnNewButton = new JButton("+");
    btnNewButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            Factura f = new Factura(tcodigo.getText(),
                    tnombre.getText(),
                    tmarca.getText(),
                    tano.getText(),
                    Integer.parseInt(tnumero.getText()),
                    tfecha.getText(),
                    Double.parseDouble(tprecio.getText()),
                    Integer.parseInt(tcantidad.getText())
                    );
            
            DefaultTableModel modelo = (DefaultTableModel) tablefactura.getModel();
            Object [] fila = new Object [7];
            
            fila[0] = f.getCodigo();
            fila[1] = f.getNombre();
            fila[2] = f.getMarca();
            fila[3] = f.getAño();
            fila[4] = f.getCantidad();
            fila[5] = f.getPrecio();
            fila[6] = String.valueOf(f.getPrecio()*f.getCantidad());
            modelo.addRow(fila);
            
        }
    });
    btnNewButton.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 18));
    btnNewButton.setBounds(10, 410, 89, 34);
    Vendedores.add(btnNewButton);
    
    JLabel label = new JLabel("0.00");
    label.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 15));
    label.setBounds(595, 135, 46, 14);
    Vendedores.add(label);
    
    JComboBox comboBox = new JComboBox();
    comboBox.setModel(new DefaultComboBoxModel(new String[] {"Abono", "Finalizado"}));
    comboBox.setBounds(558, 50, 97, 22);
    Vendedores.add(comboBox);
    
    JLabel lblPago = new JLabel("Pago:");
    lblPago.setBounds(520, 54, 37, 14);
    Vendedores.add(lblPago);
    
    JLabel lblAo = new JLabel("A\u00F1o");
    lblAo.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 15));
    lblAo.setBounds(294, 108, 54, 20);
    Vendedores.add(lblAo);

   //AQUI EL BOTON DE PRINT *************************************
    
    JButton btnPrint = new JButton("Print");
    btnPrint.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        }
    });
    btnPrint.setBounds(115, 419, 89, 23);
    Vendedores.add(btnPrint);
    
    
    
    
    
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    tabbedPane.addTab("Vendedores", null, panel, null);
    
    //MOSTRAR VEHICULOS EN LAS TABLAS
    
    Conect conexion = new Conect();
    Connection conect = conexion.conectar();
    
    String mysql = "SELECT * FROM vehículos";
    
    DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel();
    
    model.addColumn("Código");
    model.addColumn("Modelo");
    model.addColumn("Marca");
    model.addColumn("Color");
    model.addColumn("Combustible");
    model.addColumn("Año");
    model.addColumn("Precio");
    
    table.setModel(model);
    
    String[] dato = new String [7];
    
    try {
        
        Statement st = conect.createStatement();
        
        ResultSet result = st.executeQuery(mysql);
        
        while (result.next()) {
            dato[0]=result.getString(1);
            dato[1]=result.getString(2);
            dato[2]=result.getString(3);
            dato[3]=result.getString(4);
            dato[4]=result.getString(5);
            dato[5]=result.getString(6);
            dato[6]=result.getString(7);
            model.addRow(dato);
            
            
        }
        
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    
    
  }
}
```

Comment: Creo que lo que quieres es generar un reporte, con la información de tu registro. mira información sobre jasperreports con ireports, que te permite crear informes de manera gráfica.

Comment: y cual es tu pregunta?